# TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined Webpack

Tags: reactjs, npm, webpack, antd

I'm trying to create a demo of `ant-design` for that I've installed ant-design and now when I'm hitting

```
npm start
```

I got this error

```
           dora: listened on 8000
  1/2 build modules/opt/lampp/htdocs/antddemo/node_modules/webpack/lib/ExternalModuleFactoryPlugin.js:19
                        const dependency = data.dependencies[0];
                                                            ^

TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
    at /opt/lampp/htdocs/antddemo/node_modules/webpack/lib/ExternalModuleFactoryPlugin.js:19:40
    at /opt/lampp/htdocs/antddemo/node_modules/atool-build/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:159:3
    at NormalModuleFactory.<anonymous> (/opt/lampp/htdocs/antddemo/node_modules/atool-build/node_modules/tapable/lib/Tapable.js:82:11)
    at /opt/lampp/htdocs/antddemo/node_modules/npm-install-webpack-plugin-cn/src/plugin.js:24:7
    at /opt/lampp/htdocs/antddemo/node_modules/atool-build/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/UnsafeCachePlugin.js:24:19
    at onResolved (/opt/lampp/htdocs/antddemo/node_modules/atool-build/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:38:18)
    at innerCallback (/opt/lampp/htdocs/antddemo/node_modules/atool-build/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:94:11)
    at loggingCallbackWrapper (/opt/lampp/htdocs/antddemo/node_modules/atool-build/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/createInnerCallback.js:21:19)
    at /opt/lampp/htdocs/antddemo/node_modules/atool-build/node_modules/tapable/lib/Tapable.js:134:6
    at /opt/lampp/htdocs/antddemo/node_modules/atool-build/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/ModulesInDirectoriesPlugin.js:54:23
```

I tried couple of solutions but since I'm new to `ant-design` it's getting hard to digest the concept. Is there anyone for me to fix this?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Can you share the file where this declaration (`const dependency = data.dependencies[0];`) happens ?
And your webpack config ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved this by following installation

```
install extract-text-webpack-plugin@^2.0.0-beta
```

**REF:** [Webpack Issue#2764](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/2764)