# ERROR in Cannot read property '0' of undefined after upgrade to Angular 10

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I upgraded my angular application from version 8 to version 10. Now after running ng serve I am getting below one-liner error
**ERROR in Cannot read property '0' of undefined**
This looks very abstract error.

I tried clearing npm cache, deleted the package.lock.json file, deleted node_modules, and install the npm packages again but nothing seems to help me.

Below is my package.json file

```
{
  "name": "app-name",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@agm/core": "^1.1.0",
    "@agm/js-marker-clusterer": "^1.1.0",
    "@angular/animations": "~10.0.9",
    "@angular/cdk": "~10.1.3",
    "@angular/common": "~10.0.9",
    "@angular/compiler": "~10.0.9",
    "@angular/core": "~10.0.9",
    "@angular/forms": "~10.0.9",
    "@angular/material": "^10.1.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~10.0.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~10.0.9",
    "@angular/router": "~10.0.9",
    "@types/googlemaps": "^3.39.12",
    "angular-material-badge": "^1.2.91",
    "angular-notifier": "^6.0.1",
    "azure-maps-control": "^2.0.20",
    "bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
    "crypto-js": "^4.0.0",
    "dateformat": "^3.0.3",
    "dropbox": "^5.2.1",
    "iv-viewer": "^2.0.1",
    "js-marker-clusterer": "^1.0.0",
    "mammoth": "^1.4.9",
    "ng-inline-svg": "^10.0.0",
    "ng2-image-viewer": "^3.0.5",
    "ng2-pdf-viewer": "^6.0.2",
    "ngx-doc-viewer": "1.0.0",
    "ngx-light-carousel": "1.0.20",
    "ngx-pagination": "^5.0.0",
    "ngx-perfect-scrollbar": "^9.0.0",
    "ngx-permissions": "^7.0.3",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.2",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.6.2",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1000.5",
    "@angular/cli": "~10.0.5",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~10.0.9",
    "@angular/language-service": "~10.0.9",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.5.12",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "@types/office-js": "^1.0.123",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~5.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~3.3.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.10.2",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~3.9.7"
  }
}
```

I am using node 12.15.0 version and npm version 6.13.4.
Please help.

Comment: Please add the traceback if you can

Comment: @TheOtterlord How we can add traceback?

Comment: Add **all** output that was given by the terminal after you ran your command

Comment: You should be getting an error traceback that shows where does the rror come from, from which class. Just copy/paste that traceback in your question, or only your class that causes the error.

Comment: @TheOtterlord There is no detailed error. Only one line error. This is the only information I have.

Comment: Hmm, this is very odd as there should be some sort of reference to the file and line of the error. I'm afraid that without it, it is not really possible to help you. Is your 'one line error' copy pasted with all information?

Comment: @TheOtterlord, Yes

Comment: does `ng serve --aot` provide more information about error?

Comment: Actually, thinking about flags, what do you get for `ng serve --verbose=true`?

Comment: cjs require module [./node_modules/url/node_modules/punycode/punycode.js] 1:0-47
 [./node_modules/webpack/hot/emitter.js] (webpack)/hot/emitter.js 75 bytes {vendor} [built]
     cjs require webpack/hot/emitter [./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/utils/reloadApp.js] (webpack)-dev-server/client/utils/reloadApp.js 21:21-51
 [./node_modules/webpack/hot/log.js] (webpack)/hot/log.js 1.34 KiB {vendor} [optional] [built] context element ./log [./node_modules/webpack/hot sync ^\.\/log$] (webpack)/hot sync nonrecursive ^\.\/log$ ./log
ERROR in Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Comment: The webpack dependancy is throwing an error, but I don't know which of your dependancies are causing this. The same thing happened here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46929386/typeerror-cannot-read-property-0-of-undefined-webpack

Comment: I added my answer. And I noted that you have `"@types/googlemaps": "^3.39.12"` under dependencies instead of devDependencies (I don't think this can be the problem).

Comment: I had the exact same error. In my case the issue was incorrect import paths. I moved one folder to a different path in the project. Services inside the folder were used in other components. I missed to change import path in few components. After correcting imports in all components the issue got resolved.

Comment: Can you run `ng lint --fix` and see if this will tell you where your error is? I once had this error and it happened that the problem was not in my dependacy but my code itself

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's all about wrong imports. You are trying to import the files that does not exist or their location is different :)

Comment: For some reason the auto update import function of vs code skipped some files after I had moved them.  On top, vs code didn't highlight these errors as per usual.  I looked at my last commits, searched for changes related to imports and managed find the culprits.

Comment: helped me. after moving several components into different folder - some interfaces wasnt updated with proper location

Answer (score 5):

I'm having the same issue. I tracked down the stack trace by running ng serve in the vs code debugger and having it break on unhandled errors.

For me the error is:

```
Exception has occurred: TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
  at Object.typeToValue (/workingcopypath//node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/ngtsc/reflection/src/type_to_value.js:45:66)
    at /workingcopypath//node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/ngtsc/reflection/src/typescript.js:75:58
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at TypeScriptReflectionHost.getConstructorParameters (/workingcopypath//node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/ngtsc/reflection/src/typescript.js:57:36)
    at Object.getConstructorDependencies (/workingcopypath//node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/ngtsc/annotations/src/util.js:29:36)
    at extractInjectableCtorDeps (/workingcopypath//node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/ngtsc/annotations/src/injectable.js:232:72)
    at InjectableDecoratorHandler.analyze (/workingcopypath//node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/ngtsc/annotations/src/injectable.js:72:31)
    at TraitCompiler.analyzeTrait (/workingcopypath//node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/ngtsc/transform/src/compilation.js:346:40)
    at analyze (/workingcopypath//node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/ngtsc/transform/src/compilation.js:298:58)
    at _loop_1 (/workingcopypath//node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/ngtsc/transform/src/compilation.js:320:21)
    at TraitCompiler.analyzeClass (/workingcopypath//node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/ngtsc/transform/src/compilation.js:326:35)
    at visit (/workingcopypath//node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/ngtsc/transform/src/compilation.js:108:27)
    at visitNodes (/workingcopypath//node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:18956:30)
    at Object.forEachChild (/workingcopypath//node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:19189:24)
    at visit (/workingcopypath//node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/ngtsc/transform/src/compilation.js:110:20)
    at TraitCompiler.analyze (/workingcopypath//node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/ngtsc/transform/src/compilation.js:112:13)
```

The failing code in question is this line:

```
return noValueDeclaration(typeNode, decl.declarations[0]);
```

I'm still looking for the fix, but at least this should help debug the issue.

You can do this using this `.vscode/launch.json`

```
{
  // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
  // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
  // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Debug Ng Serve",
      "skipFiles": ["<node_internals>/**"],
      "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
      "program": "./node_modules/.bin/ng",
      "args": ["serve", "--verbose=true"]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I had this error too. I was missing to add all the packages I used in my code in the `package.json` depencencies (in my case *ng-bootstrap*), after this the error vanished.

Answer (score 2):

I also spent a few minutes checking the issue and the simple `ng lint` was definitely not throw me to missing or failed imports, but when executing the ng lint with various flags like this:

```
ng lint --force=true --typeCheck=true
```

I found other things that helped me get to the error.

I had to go into each Page/Component and Module to check one by one.

Toggle all the VS Code folders and checking the **"Problems"** tab of the VS Code and thus right the imports.

This happened to me replicating one project to another and removing unused references and so on.

Answer (score 2):

Since Angular didn't manage to provide a meaningful error description, let's ask TypeScript compiler for it. In my case it worked like a charm, showing the exact place and reason:

```
tsc --project <path-to-your-project>/tsconfig.json
```

Pay attention, in case of several tsconfig's, use the one intended to build your application, it might be `tsconfig.app.json` whatever. You can find it out under the `options.tsConfig` section of `angular.json`.

Answer (score 1):

Run the build in dev mode. `ng build` and it points the error at the exact place.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you have already fixed this problem, but I've solved it by updating Angular (and it's dependencies) into 10.1.2

Here's what I have actually.

```
dependencies": {
"@angular/animations": "~10.1.2",
"@angular/cdk": "^10.2.2",
"@angular/common": "~10.1.2",
"@angular/compiler": "~10.1.2",
"@angular/core": "~10.1.2",
"@angular/forms": "~10.1.2",
"@angular/material": "^10.2.2",
"@angular/platform-browser": "~10.1.2",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~10.1.2",
"@angular/router": "~10.1.2",
"rxjs": "~6.5.5",
"tslib": "^2.0.0",
"zone.js": "~0.10.  
},

"devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1000.2",
    "@angular/cli": "~10.0.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~10.1.3",
    "@types/angular": "^1.7.3",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.5.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~5.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~3.3.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~3.9.5"
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I got this error every time a ran `ng build` or `ng serve` after a big merge. The only way that worked for me was by 'divide and conquer'. I have moved to a new (test) branch and isolated/deleted all new modules/components/files that have come from merge and after every change I ran `ng build`. When the error disappeared, I did undo previously deleted files and isolated smaller and smaller chunks until I got to the source of error. For me it was a wrong import path.

Comment: Yeah, I hit this thing twice in two months. All my changes were in a single parent folder, so I searched for old imports I needed to update. I'm hoping it gets fixed in 10.1.2 like the other answer said, but maybe it is a different issue.

Answer (score 1):

*Virendra Singh Rathore* is right

> It's all about wrong imports. Your are trying to import the files that do not exist or their location is different :)

In my situation, the error appeared after transferring classes to another file. VS code didn't show the error location. I had to open all the files and look for corrupted 'imports'.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error after updating from Angular 9 to 10.

The problem was solved for me after updating dev dependencies:

```
npm update --save-dev
```

Answer (score 0):

In my Case -->

```
import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';  //main.ts file
import { ApicallService } from 'src/app/services/apicall.service'; //In a component file
```

These are are the reasons that showing me ERROR in Cannot read property '0' of undefined
Error. So I solved it with changing the paths.

```
import { AppModule } from './app/app/app.module'; //main.ts file
import { ApicallService } from 'src/app/app/services/apicall.service';
```

Answer (score 0):

We had the same issue. After trying everything from this list, we updated all the dependencies and the message which was given was more descriptive.
It was one import path that wasn't set correctly that caused the issue.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it's very basic one.  when I'm trying to "service" in my "component", i imported like

```
import  SetPasswordService  from './set-password.service';
```

But after checking each line, I added "curly braces" it's gone.

```
import { SetPasswordService } from './set-password.service';
```